# CMake Error: MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR not found

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake, mysqlpp

I am trying to establish connection with `MySQL` in C++. For that i am using [sqlpp11](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11) and it's [connector](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11-connector-mysql).

1. `sqlpp11` successfully build.
2. `sqllpp11-connector-mysql` is not building properly because of some cmake error.

   CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
       Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
       MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR (ADVANCED)

This is how my my `CmakeList.txt` looks

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
include(CheckCXXSymbolExists)
project (sqlpp11-connector-mysql)
enable_testing()
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

check_cxx_symbol_exists(_LIBCPP_VERSION iostream HAS_LIBCPP_VERSION)
if (HAS_LIBCPP_VERSION)
    message("libc++ does not have thread_local, thus we need to wrap that via boost thread")
    find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread)
endif()


set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(MySql REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "Using ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} (compiler id: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID})")

set(DATE_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../date" CACHE FILEPATH "Path to Howard Hinnant's date library")

if(NOT EXISTS ${DATE_INCLUDE_DIR}/date.h)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Can't find file date.h")
    message("Can't find date.h in ${DATE_INCLUDE_DIR} ")
    message("Please either")
    message("  - git clone https://github.com/howardhinnant/date ${DATE_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message("  - download and unzip a current version from https://github.com/howardhinnant/date to ${DATE_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message("  - set DATE_INCLUDE_DIR to point to the dir containing date.h from the date library")
    message("")
else()
    message("including date from ${DATE_INCLUDE_DIR}")
endif()

set(SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../sqlpp11/include" CACHE FILEPATH "Path to sqlpp11 includes")

if(NOT EXISTS ${SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR}/sqlpp11/sqlpp11.h)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Can't find file sqlpp11/sqlpp11.h")
    message("Can't find sqlpp11/sqlpp11.h in ${SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR} ")
    message("Please either")
    message("  - git clone https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11 ${SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message("  - download and unzip a current version from https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11 to ${SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message("  - set DATE_INCLUDE_DIR to point to the dir containing sqlpp11/sqlpp11.h")
    message("")
else()
    message("including sqlpp11 from ${SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR}")
endif()

set(MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include/sqlpp11/mysql" CACHE FILEPATH "PATH TO sqllpp11/mysql")

include_directories("${SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR}")
include_directories("${DATE_INCLUDE_DIR}")
include_directories("${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
set(include_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
file(GLOB_RECURSE sqlpp_headers ${include_dir}/*.h ${SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.h)
include_directories(${include_dir})

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tests)

install(DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/sqlpp11" DESTINATION include)
```

Comment: What do you want to achive by setting variable `MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR` **after** `find_package(MySql REQUIRED)` call? If `find_package` succeed, it already sets this variable. If `find_package` fails, it immediately terminates configuration (because of *REQUIRED* option). Moreover, you are trying to set *cached* variable, which is always no-op as variable *is already set* by `find_package` to either directory path or `-NOFOUND`. In short, for hint `find_package` set variable *before* it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev : I tried to set variable before, `find_package` but it produces the same error.

Comment: So, what value of *cache entry* `MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR`? You may find it in `CMakeCache.txt` located in build directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev : I solved the problem. I was missing a package `libmysqlclient-dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `CmakeList.txt` provided in [sqlpp11-connector-mysql](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11-connector-mysql) is perfect. I don't need to edit it.

Apart from that i needed to install `libmysqlclient-dev` and it work like charm.

Comment: So, based on that, you're using an rpm-based Linux distro and were missing the header files?

Comment: @ILMostro_7 : I guess, yes.

Comment: The sqlpp11-connector-mysql repo says libmysqlclient5.5 or greater is needed, but it doesn't mention the header files.  When you're building from source, those are needed indeed.

Comment: Though, I take back the rpm-based distro assumption :)

Comment: @ILMostro_7 : :), If you are interested, i have another problem, help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're setting `MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR`, but then

```
include_directories("${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

notice the extra S.